# UWP and mvc core 1

Tags: asp.net-core, uwp

I am trying to determine if I can develop a single application that targets both native windows client
And the web.

I have been reading up on UWP.   In my reading I have come across two different flavors.  One
That uses the new core 1 with a shared api layer and then develops different client applications
For the windows native client and the web.      I am trying to understand if there is a second
Option that creates a website that can be used to generate a native windows executable.
I have read about windows 10 host web applications and this is not a native executable.
I have also read about xamarin, I know this can create native clients for IOS and Android,
But I don’t see anything for native windows.

I have ran across UWP hosted web applications.. But from what I can see this does not solve
What I am looking for.  From what I can figure out the hosted web application is still a
Web app that has views targeted to the different platforms.

If it is possible to create a web application that can create a native windows executable then
The next question I have is does this website have to fully SPA (using angularJS) or can I 
Use a hybrid MVC core 1 (with Javascript for immediate screen responses).

Comment: There are no Microsoft provided tools that generate a HTML and "native windows" UI from a single codebase. If you want a single UI for both then using HTML is probably the way to go. What's your reason for not wanting to use a hosted web app? I've heard of a few companies in the past who've tried to build tools to create web and desktop UIs but none have really taken off.

Comment: From what I have read the hosted web app allows the app to be in the Microsoft store (and a few other thing)... This app will never be in the store so I don't see value to move the existing web application.   If I could combine the existing native application and the existing web app into one code base, then this is a value add.